# arm64 packages not installed into arm64 sysroot, so CMake doesn't find them

Tags: cmake, cross-compilation, crossplatform

I need to cross compile an application, using CMake. I install the toolchain packages and the arm64 versions of my dependencies. Looks like the sysroot is in `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu`, which contains some system lib and headers, but the package libs and headers end up in `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu` and `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu`.

Now, setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu` finds system libs, but not my installed ones. Why aren't the packages installed into the sysroot? How do I let CMake know about this?

Comment: Do you consider native compilation (RaspberryPi or something)?